# nginx: pass to php only specific urls

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I need to process with php only some specific urls, like:

```
 http://10.0.0.1/orange
 http://10.0.0.1/pear
 http://10.0.0.1/apple
```

any other strings, like:

```
 http://10.0.0.1/orange/
 http://10.0.0.1/orangeee
 http://10.0.0.1/ora.gif
 http://10.0.0.1/orange.php
```

must be blocked with 404 or 400 (better)

this is my server block:

```
server {
    listen 10.0.0.1:80;
    server_name 10.0.0.1;
    root /usr/share/nginx/;
    location ~ ^ (apple|orange|pear)$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/processor.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        expires -1;
    }
}
```

It doesn works as expected:

Request:

```
POST http://10.0.0.1/orange
```

Resonse:

```
404
```

The error log reports:

```
open() "/usr/share/nginx/orange" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

p.s. simple locations like:

```
location /orange {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/processor.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    expires -1;
}
```

works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the space after the `^` with a `/`, making the regex like this `^/(apple|orange|pear)$`

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your regex: `^ (apple|orange|pear)$`

Remove the space after `^`.